# Confusion regarding action and category

Tags: android

I am new to the android as a programmer.In the android manifest file we have the code as:

```
<activity
 android:name".Class1"
 android:label="Myapp">
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER/>
 </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Question**

Why do we need to specify the category LAUNCHER, when we have specified the action to be MAIN which is enough to tell the android that Class1 is going to be initial activity of my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ACTION_MAIN` is required Action to be performed.It is the main or starting point and wont expect any data.

`CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` The activity is the initial activity of a task and is listed in the system's application launcher.

You could refer these links

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
 [What is the meaning of android.intent.action.MAIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219551/what-is-the-meaning-of-android-intent-action-main)

Comment: What do you mean by task?

Comment: I basically mean that the Activity will show up in the launcher

Comment: take a look at launchMode for activity you would better understand tasks

Answer (score 0):

`"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"` means this activity will display an icon in the launcher home screen. Without this category , you can't see its icon  in launcher home screen.

`android.intent.action.MAIN` means this activity is a entry point of your app.