# Android studio - cant find my app on device after building

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I'm using android studio 1.3 , I'm running/debugging my app on my Nexus 5 - works great but after exiting the app - I cant find my app on the device..
so actually every time I want to run it I need to connect my device to the studio and run...

It happened suddenly , in the past I ran the program and it did! Stay on the device
Tried on different devices.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.meantneat.com.meetneat"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url 'http://lorenzo.villani.me/android-cropimage/'
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    //compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.0'
    //compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'me.villani.lorenzo.android:android-cropimage:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'




    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks, Dan

Comment: have you checked on Other devices also m are you sure  the problem is with android studio?

Comment: yes, and also from other mac with android studio

Comment: adb install <path_to_your_bin>.apk  have you tried this is this working??

Comment: @Dev where can i find my apk?

Comment: app/build/outputs/apk

Comment: @Dev Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]

Comment: go to settings apps in your phone , the error says that its already in phone , you have to uninstall it in order to install new apk

Comment: @Dev added -r - succes but still cant see the app , if i go to device app settings it's their

Comment: is it runnning on emulator?, I mean can you see the app icon in menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Manifest mark one of your activity as launcher activity :

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: thats what i have:<activity
            android:name=".Controller.MainAndSettings.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASH" />
               
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: add <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> as well

Comment: @HarishSridharan is correct. You have to mention inside Intent Filter of your activity an action as "android.intent.action.MAIN". 
The Android System looks for this "action" inside all the activities of the installed Apps, when launching the Application Launcher.

Comment: added android.intent.action.MAIN - works! THANK YOU!!

Comment: @HarishSridharan in case if "android.intent.action.MAIN is not set the app will not launch any activity!! or will it?

Comment: @Dev It will. The usage of MAIN is to indicate the android OS to consider the particular activity when the OS will be querying all the application to get the entry points. A device will have # of apps and each app will itself have huge number of activities, it can't be searching every activity whether to enter or not for a particular purpose. Thus comes the purpose of MAIN. In simple terms, android OS will query only the MAIN activities when it needs to gain an entry access to an application. You may also read this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25219614/3894784