# why the app is not running on my cellphone?

Tags: android

I'm debugging my app and for some reason it does not load the app to my smartphone.
i have no idea why it happenes. it shows that there are no earrors and succsessfull launched, but nothing happenes.

**This is the activity**

```
public class TabHostMain extends TabActivity {

TabHost tabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_host_main);


    tabHost = getTabHost();

    TabHost.TabSpec ts1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("main");
    ts1.setIndicator("Main");
    ts1.setContent(new Intent(this, Main.class));
    tabHost.addTab(ts1);

    TabHost.TabSpec ts2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("GPS");
    ts2.setIndicator("GPS");
    ts2.setContent(new Intent(this, GPS.class));
    tabHost.addTab(ts2);


    TabHost.TabSpec ts3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Info");
    ts3.setIndicator("Info");
    ts3.setContent(new Intent(this, Info.class));
    tabHost.addTab(ts3);

}
```

}

**this is the manifest**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Main" />
    <activity android:name=".GPS" />
    <activity android:name=".Info" />
    <activity android:name=".TabHostMain"/>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"></activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is no launched activity declared in your Android Manifest.

Make the following change in your android manifest and it will work.

```
<activity android:name=". Main2Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because you don't have any `launcher` and `main` activity declared in your `manifest` file, add this intent tag to one of the activites in the manifest file and it will work, you should do something like this :

```
<activity android:name=".Main">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Read more about these intent filters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219551/what-is-the-meaning-of-android-intent-action-main).