# Difference between having intent.category.HOME alone in AndroidManifest.xml and also with intent.category.DEFAULT at the same time

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

What are the differences between:

```
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

and:

```
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727828/what-is-the-purpose-of-android-intent-category-default

Answer (score 1):

**See the answer Here**

[What is the meaning of android.intent.action.MAIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219551/what-is-the-meaning-of-android-intent-action-main)

`android.intent.action.MAIN` means that this activity is the entry point of the application, i.e. when you launch the application, this activity is created.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

```
ACTION_MAIN with category CATEGORY_HOME -- Launch the home screen.
```

Also,from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN)

> Activity Action Start as a main entry point, does not expect to
>   receive data.

**android.intent.category.DEFAULT** is mainly used for implicit intents. If your activity wishes to be started by an implicit intent it should include this catetory in its filter.
If your Activity might be started by an implicit Intent when no specific category is assigned to it, its Intent filter should include this category.

See the docs..

1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
2. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element.html

and Another View of @CommonsWare .... in that answer also.... See it

So that `ACTION_MAIN` is considered an entry point for the application.

Usually, it combines with `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` in an `<intent-filter>` to indicate an activity that should appear in the home screen's launcher, or in anything else that considers itself to be a launcher. Such "launchers" can query `PackageManager`, using `queryIntentActivities()`, to find such activities and display them to the user.

However, `ACTION_MAIN` can be used in combination with other categories for other specialized purposes. For example, `CATEGORY_CAR_DOCK` with `ACTION_MAIN` indicates an activity that should be considered a candidate to be shown when the user drops their phone into a manufacturer-supplied car dock.

When an `Intent` is used with `startActivity()`, if the `Intent` is not already placed into a category, it is placed into `CATEGORY_DEFAULT`. Hence, an `<activity>` `<intent-filter>` needs to specify *some* `<category>`, using `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` if nothing else.